# Printing the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

For some reason, I am unable to print the entire linked list. Where could I be going wrong?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

The basic structure of the list.

```
struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node *list;
```

Main function.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    list head = NULL, start = NULL, temp, p;

    printf("Enter the number of nodes in the list: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
```

Formation of the linked list.

```
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        if (i==0)
        {
            start = (list) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            start->num = i;
            head = start;
            head->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {   
            temp = (list) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->num = i;
            head->next = temp;
            head->next = NULL;
        }
    }
```

Printing the linked list.

```
    p = start;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", p->num);
        p = p->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't you missing here something:

```
head->next = temp;
head->next = NULL;
```

You are overriding your next `head` with `NULL`. You should have your `head` at first point to `temp`.

```
head->next = temp;   // (4) see my comment on this post for 
head = temp;         // (5) the meaning of the number
head->next = NULL;   // (6)
```

Edit: By the way, you should rename `head` to `current`/`last` or something like that. Else, one could easily swap the meaning of `head` and `start`.

Comment: Won't the 2nd element be overridden as well with this suggestion for a list of size >=3?

Comment: No? Dont confuse me unneccessarily >.<. Anyway, I tested the code just now since I could not see where I was wrong and the output proved to be right!

Comment: It's a question - I am not sure myself :| - it seems that the original `head->next` is not saved and will be discarded, but as I said - I am not sure, thus the question.

Comment: As I see it, when starting the scope, (1) `head` is already correctly initialized. (2) Then the other fields of `temp` are being initialized (`int`). Since `head` is pointing to our last item, (3) we are going to make his `next`pointer point to our new item. Now our last item is initialized entirely and we do not need the pointer to it anymore, (4) so we can make our new item to the new `head`. (5) The new `head` of course points to `NULL`, with what our `head` would be correctly initialized as in (1) required.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. `head` in your suggestion is pointing to the last element actually, and thus it should work just fine. I could not follow it properly - thus I asked. This - in addition to your edit regarding renaming worthes a +1.

Answer (score 3):

```
        temp = (list) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->num = i;
        head->next = temp;
        head->next = NULL;
```

You place the new element always as the 2nd element, and then remove it - effectively making your list of constant size 1.

You probably need to set `temp->next = NULL` (instead of `head->next`) **and** set `element->next = temp` - where `element` is the last element in the list (and not the `head`). 

(An alternative is to add the element as the new `head`, and set `temp->next = head;`)

Comment: I got to know where I was going wrong. Thanks for replying. :)